# Como insertar datos desde un formulario en dos tablas mysql relacionadas?

Tags: java, mysql

Como pueden ver en la siguiente imagen, necesito insertar datos en esas dos tablas relacionadas y desde un mismo formulario, ya que en el formulario pido toda la información de la tabla cliente y también varias direcciones del mismo.

lenguaje:java.
base de datos: mysql.
tecnologías: jsp, servlet.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola toty, bienvenid@ a Stack Overflow, te sugiero completar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganar tu primera medalla :D También puedes revisar la sección de [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para que tu preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad.

Answer (score -1):

Podrías guardar el valor obtenido desde el formulario en variables y realizar dos Insert por separado.

Aquí aclaran que puede ser en una misma transacción con la base de datos, más no en una sola declaración (statement).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/175066/sql-server-is-it-possible-to-insert-into-two-tables-at-the-same-time

Comment: Hola Daniel, no te he votado negativo, pero me imagino que la persona que lo hizo fue por esta razon: [no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/3217#3217). Te invito a que visites el link y aprovecho para darte la bienvenida :)

Comment: Hola  @KacosPro, gracias por tu sugerencia y bienvenida.
Tu consideras que el voto negativo también haya sido por poner una referencia en ingles?
Por lo que entendí, entonces tuve que haber comentado pidiendo más información antes de contesta?